# Protected Sub name.ValueChanged not updating

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net

Why when a user chooses a different choice from dropdown does the Line1Co.Value always stay at 0?

Here is my HTML:

```
       <asp:DropDownList ID="HandLine1Size" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" Width="110px">
            <asp:ListItem Value="1">1.75</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="1.5625">2</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="2.25">2.5</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="3.0625">3</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="0">No handline</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList
<asp:HiddenField ID="Line1Co" runat="server" />
<br />
    <%= Line1Co.Value %>
```

Here is my Code Behind:

```
Protected Sub Line1Co_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Line1Co.ValueChanged
    If HandLine1Size.SelectedValue = "1" Then Line1Co.Value = "12" Else 
    If HandLine1Size.SelectedValue = "1.5625" Then Line1Co.Value = "8" Else 
    If HandLine1Size.SelectedValue = "2.25" Then Line1Co.Value = "2" Else 
    If HandLine1Size.SelectedValue = "3.0625" Then Line1Co.Value = "0.75" Else 
    Line1Co.Value = "20"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems in your code:

1. You should handle the `SelectedIndexChanged` of the DropDownList instead of the `ValueChanged` event of the HiddenField.
2. The single-line `if` statements look incorrect to me with the `Else` at the end. The last line is always executed and the value is set to `"20"` in all cases.

---

Here are a few ways to achieve what you want.

With single-line `if` statements:

```
Protected Sub HandLine1Size_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles HandLine1Size.SelectedIndexChanged
    Line1Co.Value = "20"
    If HandLine1Size.SelectedValue = "1" Then Line1Co.Value = "12"
    If HandLine1Size.SelectedValue = "1.5625" Then Line1Co.Value = "8"
    If HandLine1Size.SelectedValue = "2.25" Then Line1Co.Value = "2"
    If HandLine1Size.SelectedValue = "3.0625" Then Line1Co.Value = "0.75"
End Sub
```

With a multiline `if` statement:

```
Protected Sub HandLine1Size_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles HandLine1Size.SelectedIndexChanged
    If HandLine1Size.SelectedValue = "1" Then
        Line1Co.Value = "12"
    ElseIf HandLine1Size.SelectedValue = "1.5625" Then
        Line1Co.Value = "8"
    ElseIf HandLine1Size.SelectedValue = "2.25" Then
        Line1Co.Value = "2"
    ElseIf HandLine1Size.SelectedValue = "3.0625" Then
        Line1Co.Value = "0.75"
    Else
        Line1Co.Value = "20"
    End If
End Sub
```

With a `Select` statement:

```
Protected Sub HandLine1Size_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles HandLine1Size.SelectedIndexChanged
    Select Case HandLine1Size.SelectedValue
        Case "1"
            Line1Co.Value = "12"
        Case "1.5625"
            Line1Co.Value = "8"
        Case "2.25"
            Line1Co.Value = "2"
        Case "3.0625"
            Line1Co.Value = "0.75"
        Case Else
            Line1Co.Value = "20"
    End Select
End Sub
```